# Dynamic Shortcode in WooCommerce Downloads

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I'm selling unique, custom files in Woocommerce, and currently link to the final files with a shortcode that dynamically links to the final file. The shortcode doesn't register in Woocommerce's Product Downloads Settings (Woo doesn't recognize "[]").

Is it possible to have a shortcode link in Woocommerce's Downloadable Files settings?